# Is it safe to travel to Kiev at the moment?

Tags: safety, international-travel, ukraine, kyiv

I know there is war in the Eastern part of Ukraine at the moment but how is the situation in Kiev? Is it safe to travel there at the moment?

Comment: What is `safe` to you? See [this meta question](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1906/personal-safety) for help on how to render the question less opinion-based.

Comment: In 2014 [more than 2 million tourists](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2014/aug/25/tourism-suffers-in-crimea-as-ukraine-shuns-breakaw/?page=all) visited Crimea alone, and that'd be the arguably more dangerous spot, as viewed by outsiders.   But how do you want an answer? Can I just say 'uber safe, you'll be fine' or 'terrifying, run away'?  Please do have a look at the meta and the [help] on asking subjective questions on safety - perhaps asking for some crime statistics against tourists would be a better solution. In its current state it's likely to be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice and make your own judgement

Comment: -1 This is somewhat a link-only answer. This is a QA site. Telling someone to RTFM doesn't really qualify as a *quality* answer. Moreover links a prone to 404-oblivion. Care to expand?